# Subversion Tortoise with powershell - automatic import of changed input and created output files

Tags: powershell, svn, automation, tortoisesvn

I am writing a powershell-script that reads an excel-file and creates some output files. Some of them will be new, some of them will only change every time the script runs.

Now I need to find a way to automatically put the excel-file, the created and the changed files to a subversion repository. Everytime the script runs, I need to automatically build a new revision.

I have no clue about subversion and could not find the right commands.

What I tried by now is:

```
$svn= 'C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe'
& $svn import -m $SVNmessage $SVNPfad $SVNURL --force
& $svn add --force "${SVNPfad}Excel" --auto-props --parents --depth infinity -q 
& $svn update $SVNPfad --force --accept mine-conflict
& $svn commit -m $SVNmessage $SVNPfad
& $svn checkout $SVNPfad
```

In my opinion I need to have checkout as the last command to let the user change the excel file or to let him add a new excel file and to not destroy it with my update command.

I am new to stackoverflow, so please tell me whenever I did anything wrong.

Thanks!

Tim